# What determines operational task replacement cost?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Patch 0.12.12.15.4 introduced a method to reroll **operational tasks**, usually resulting in a different task. The [patch notes](https://forum.escapefromtarkov.com/topic/164509-patch-notes-for-01212154/) do clarify that subsequent replacements will be more expensive (emphasis mine):

> Added the ability to replace an operational task in the trader quest
> menu. The replaced task will be considered failed. The **cost of each
> subsequent replacement will increase until the task’s completion timer
> runs out**

Last week, my first replacement was about 40k rubles, the second somewhere in the 100k rubles area, the third about 250k rubles. Today my first replacement is 30k, the second closer to 3M:

[image: Operational task replacement cost: ₽ 2712995]

The exact amounts are likely changing depending on the base value of the task in question, which in turn appears to be based off my completion history and/or level. But the continuous, now 100-fold increase, only starting with the *second* replacement per day, seems to be a separate pattern.

Something is adding to my cost well beyond *those replaced task’s completion timer*. Is there any consistent logic behind cost modifiers and their expiry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved for PMC operational tasks at some point in June, and has now [also been fixed](https://forum.escapefromtarkov.com/topic/84556-eft-newsticker/?do=findComment&comment=2064715) for the since newly introduced Scav tasks for the 2022-07-01 hotfix.

> Adjusted the Scav operational task replacement cost.

Now each consecutive reroll only increases the cost by around 20%, resetting as the previously replaced task timers run out.